Why Does My Java Code to find multiple occurrences in of a Sting in another String not work?
I attempted writing a piece of Java code to check if there were multiple occurrences of a substring in another string, so if a substring appeared more than once in a string the method ought to return true, else it should return false. It worked fine when the substring was not present at all in the string but it returned true when the substring was present but did not occur more than once which isn't supposed to happen. Below is method:
public boolean twoOccurrencesMethod(String a, String b){
    int fromIndex = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int Index = b.indexOf(a, fromIndex);
    
    while((Index) != -1){
      count++;
      fromIndex = Index + 1;
      
      if (count > 1){
        return true; 
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

I expected the method to return false when the substring did not occur more than once in the string.
But with a bit of tinkering, I arrived at the below method which works perfectly.
public boolean twoOccurrencesMethod(String a, String b){
    int fromIndex = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int Index;
    
    while((Index = b.indexOf(a, fromIndex)) != -1){
      count++;
      fromIndex = Index + 1;
      
      if (count > 1){
        return true; 
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

Why exactly does initializing the Index variable in the condition of the while loop work as opposed to initializing it before the while loop like in the first method?

This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with using a debugger.  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Are you sure that the second one works as expected?

At a glance, in the first example any time Index is not -1 the method will return true on the second iteration of the loop.  Every time.  By design.

@Lal yes, the second one works

@David No, it's only supposed to return true if the count is greater than 1

@JesuiteAkhidenor: Yes, and that happens on the second iteration of the loop.  You initialize count to 0 and then call count++ twice.  Which makes count greater than 1.  The second example at least has the possibility of the loop only iterating once.  In the first example it either doesn't iterate at all or iterates twice.  Never once.  Don't assume, don't rely on what you think it "should" do, use a debugger and observe.

@David Thank you. I've tried debugging and it's as the answer says the value of Index on the second iteration of the loop doesn't update even though the value of fromIndex changed.

Take care of java naming conventions. Variable names should start with lower case character.

@Jens Thanks you.


Why exactly does initializing the Index variable in the condition of the while loop work as opposed to initializing it before the while loop like in the first method?

In the first snippit of code, you assign Index once. In the second, you assign the new value every loop.
Once you assign a value to a variable, it will only ever change if you reassign it. In the first code, Index will only ever be the value of b.indexOf(a, fromIndex), even for the second time through the loop. It doesn't automatically update when you change fromIndex, you have to tell it to recalculate (which you did when you put the assignment inside of while((Index = b.indexOf(a, fromIndex)) != -1)).
Since Index never changes, then Index != -1 never changes. Which means the while loop will always either be while (false), in which case it skips it entirely, or while (true), which would cause two iterations, raising count to be above 1, causing the return true.
Effectively, your first snippit just does this:
public boolean twoOccurrencesMethod(String a, String b) {
    int Index = b.indexOf(a, 0);
    
    if (Index != -1) {
      return true; 
    }
    return false;
}


Here is another alternative.

use a while loop
continue updating the starting location until the loop fails, while counting the occurrences.
then return the boolean based on the accumulated count.

public static boolean multipleOccurrences(String source, String target){
     int count = 0;
     int start = -1;
     while ((start = source.indexOf(target,start+1)) >= 0) {
         count++;
     }
     return count > 1; 
 }

Note that by only incrementing start by 1, the method will find shared words that start and end with the same letter.  For example roverover would report rover as being found twice.  You can correct that by incrementing by the length of the target string.  It all depends on your requirements.
public static boolean multipleOccurrences(String source, String target){
     int count = 0;
     int targetLen = target.length();
     int start = -targetLen;
  
     while ((start = source.indexOf(target,start+targetLen)) >= 0) {
         count++;
     }
     return count > 1; 
 }

And in case you didn't know, using accepted Java Naming Conventions, methods and variables are lower case while classes are upper case.

I suggest that you get a good IDE such as Eclipse or IntellJ and learn how to debug code. You have answers which work - always a good result.
However its always worth reading the documentation as you can often find shorter or easier ways to do something. Two examples, read about lastIndexOf or split as these allow the one line:
public static boolean multipleOccurrences(String source, String target){
    return source.indexOf(target) + target.length() <= source.lastIndexOf(target);
}
public static boolean multipleOccurrences(String source, String target){
    return source.split(target, -1).length > 2;
}

